# website is responsive but it is not passing the google responsive test

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsiveness

http://shapeandslim.com/

If we drag it through the chrome it show that it is responsive, also i have checked it in iphone5 safari, it works fine as well but when we try google mobile friendly test it just fails, only home page fails while rest of the pages successfully passed the mobile friendly test. Also the preview that it shows on google test page it seems like that the css is not being used. whats seems to be the problem here and how to solve it.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about your _"google responsive test"_. What is the exact tool you're using? Is it [Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) or something else?

Comment: i am using https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/ for checking the responsiveness

Comment: You def have an overflow element that may be affecting it. http://i.imgur.com/qWqsQA6.png

Answer (score 1):

I had these same problems. I found that I had a robots.txt file that was prohibiting crawling of the folder that contained my bootstrap CSS files, so it wasn't rendering correctly for crawlers. I changed all of my fonts to ensure they are at least 16px. I also added the following to all of my images: class="img-responsive".  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From Google Webmaster FAQ

> I have a great mobile site, but the Mobile-Friendly Test tells me that my pages aren't mobile-friendly. Why?
>   If a page is designed to work well on mobile devices, but it’s not passing the Mobile-Friendly Test, the most common reason is that Googlebot for smartphones is blocked from crawling resources, like CSS and JavaScript, that are critical for determining whether the page is legible and usable on a mobile device (i.e., whether it’s mobile-friendly). To remedy:

1. Check if the Mobile-Friendly Test shows blocked resources (often
   accompanied with a partially rendered image).
2. Allow Googlebot to crawl the necessary files.
3. Double-check that your page passes the Mobile-Friendly Test.
4. Use Fetch as Google with Submit to Index and
   submit your updated robots.txt to Google to expedite the
   re-processing of the updated page (or just wait for Google to
   naturally re-crawl and index).

Source https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.dk/2015/04/faqs-april-21st-mobile-friendly.html Question 6

Answer (score -3):

The reasons according to Google as to why your site is not mobile friendly is because of the following:

1. Content wider than screen
2. Links too close together
3. Uses incompatible plugins

Another reason could be that:

> This page may appear not mobile-friendly because the robots.txt file
>   may block Googlebot from loading some of the page's resources. Learn
>   how to unblock resources for Googlebot.

Google is Rendering your website as follows, I suggest checking the cache and CSS files accordingly. Make sure the view does now exceed the size of the screen 
[image: Google Mobile Rendering]

Check the link [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?utm_source=MFT&utm_campaign=MFT&utm_medium=incoming-link&priorityGroup=USABILITY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fshapeandslim.com%2F) for more insight on your page and how to fix it